# Entering very long Google password during setup

Tags: security, password, usability

If I have a new phone how can I enter my Google password in a secure manner during setup without having to type it (it is VERY long at over 30 random alphanumeric characters and a pain to type).

Since the phone it not yet set up I have no way yo send it to myself from another device via encrypted email, messaging, PGP because I have no apps installed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well technically I don't think you need to actually setup a Google account right away. So what I would recommend is skipping the part of the setup process where you setup a Google account and then use a built in app to retrieve it (SMS, copy a file onto your phone or any method to read text).

Other than that I think the best thing would be to just temporarily change your Google password for a few minutes, than change it back right after (once you have methods to get the new password onto the phone without typing)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can shortcut, without entering the password manually, since you cannot copy and paste it from elsewhere, or receive it from elsewhere, good luck with your typing!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, There is no way for that as told by @L_Pav.

But, In new phone you can always skip those settings and do it later on whenever you are free.